# If the only thing that changes is the constructor should I still derive?

Tags: c++, generics, constructor

I have a class that has everything already implemented but its initialization process is different for every child class.
Is there a better idiom to replace the ctor?  Is there something more generic/dynamic that I should use?

Comment: Why not simply provide overloaded constructors?

Comment: Hey, we like your approach, Neil. Put it out there where we can vote it up to encourage the questioner to consider it.

Comment: It's a question, not an answer.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Because I can't overload them, they accept the same parameters with different template parameters. Sure I can specialize the ctor... Hmm that might be it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or use static factory methods. This allows you to have different names for the "constructor" that shows the intent.

Comment: I'll bet James Keesey hits the rep ceiling today.

Answer (score 5):

Does each subclass really represent a different concept than the superclass? If the only thing that changes is the initialization, and none of the data or later behavior, could you just add parameters to the constructor to control that initialization?

Comment: It just presents an abstract->concreate hierarchy. All the constructor does is connecting different events to object funcions. It's always the same operation but on different objects and even on different number of them.
Also each object might bind himself to a different set of events